# Flatten 2d or 3d Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to take a multidimensional array and flatten it so that if the array looks like:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

Then it is transformed to:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I also need to accommodate 3D arrays and flatten them also.

Here is what I've got so far...

```
class ArrayOperations {
private int[] postFlattenedArray;

public ArrayOperations {

flattenedArray = new int[arrayDimensions[0]];
// arrayDimesnsions of 3,4 is a a 3x4 array; 3,4,5 is a 3x4x5 array

//set up ints to hold total size and dimensionality of array
int prod = 1
int dimensions = 0;

newArray = new int[prod - 1];

for (int i: arrayDimensions) {
  prod = prod * i;
  dimensions += 1;
  }
int k = 0;

for ( int i: arrayDimensions ){
for ( int j = 0; j <= i; j++ ){
  newArray[k++] = flattenedArray[j][0][0]
}
}

}
```

I know I need to run some nested for loops, but I'm having difficulty grasping how I would do this for different array dimensions. So if the array has dimensions; 3,5,6 then I am not sure how to run a loop so that it iterates like:

```
[1..4][0][0], [0][1..5][0], [0][0][1..6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to that the simplest solution is implementing a recursive function `flatten` (which will probably have to be generic to be able to handle arrays of anything), which will return the array itself if already flat or recursively call itself on all the internal arrays and concatenate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void flatten(Object object, List<Integer> list) {
    if (object.getClass().isArray()) 
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object); ++i)
            flatten(Array.get(object, i), list);
    else
        list.add((int)object);
}

static int[] flatten(Object object) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    flatten(object, list);
    int size = list.size();
    int[] result = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        result[i] = list.get(i);
    return result;
}
```

and

```
int[][][] array = {
    {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}},
    {{6}, {7, 8, 9}},
};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flatten(array)));
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```